# Best Asymmetric Encryption Standard for Communications?

Tags: rsa, public-key

I'm new to the standards of encryption.  I understand the math behind RSA really well.  I'm wanting to design an application for private peer to peer communications using RSA and wanted to know what the best standard to use is.  I want the highest level of security, regardless of efficiency or wait times.

Comment: Is this for your own education or do you want to deploy this for other people?

Comment: This is for my own education and friends.  I want to develop some crypto skills because it might be a future career path for me.

Comment: Ok cool. You most likely don't want to use RSA for a chat client or something similar. You'd want to use a so-called 'hybrid' encryption scheme which does key exchange using public key cryptography and encrypts packets using symmetric cryto.

Comment: I'd look at OTR and CurveCP. Not necessarily because they're what you want to implement, but because they're interesting to study. CurveCP has similar goals as SSL/TLS but is much easier to understand. OTR is interesting because it offers strong forward secrecy and deniability.

Comment: I really appreciate you guys' help on this.  You've set me in the right direction for some good fun.  Thanks!